# Console writing, delete characters

Tags: c++, console-application

My question concerns deleting already written chars in the console. Is there a way to do it?
Lets say i write 10 spaces to the console. Can i delete some to make space for other chars without the output exeeding 10 chars?  I use a special libary given, with functions for writing in the console etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `'\b'`. It erases one character, and the cursor moves back:

```
std::cout << "nawaz"; //screen shows : nawaz
std::cout << '\b'; //'z' is erased, now screen shows : nawa
```

Comment: Huh, I've been programming C++ for many years and never knew about that escape code.

Comment: Will never delete new lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
do {

cout<<"\b"<<num--;

}

while ( num >0 );
```

Comment: so to delete the current space, i have to move the cursor to the right and then write the \b, thanks :)

Comment: @Alon_A: is that supposed to be `"\b"` instead of `"\n"`?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yep, fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of terminal you're using, you could use the [escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to control it.

For Windows, there are also API functions, if I remember correctly.